# Use of strings vs enums as parameter of factory method?

Tags: design-patterns, enums, factory, solid-principles

I was recently reading this blog https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2021/03/06/ifElseSwitch.html and this paragraph confused me:

> Be careful with that token x. Don’t try to make it an enum or anything
> that requires a declaration above the red line. An integer, or a
> string is a better choice. It may not be type safe. Indeed, it cannot
> be type safe. But it will allow you to preserve the component
> structure of your architecture.

If we declare an enum in the higher level module, wouldn't it still be that the low level module depends on the high level module? If so, then what is wrong in using an enum in this case?

Comment: I prefer this rebuttal to Uncle Bob's essay: [Coding Constructs I Now Avoid](https://danielbmarkham.com/coding-constructs-i-now-avoid/).

Answer (score 5):

The only person who can definitely answer that question is Robert C. Martin himself, but I'll try to make an attempt.

As far as I understand it, the implied scenario is that the `$input` parameter represents *run-time input*, which is inherently *not* type-safe.

In many application architectures, there's a boundary where the software 'meets the real world'. In a primitive application, you may ask the user to type *0* for *male* and *1* for *female*. In a console application, you're not even going to receive an `int` - you'll get a `string`.

In a web application you easily run into a similar problem. Even if you make a nice GUI with, say, radio buttons, you can't fully trust that some malign user wouldn't try to circumvent the GUI to instead give you a raw `string` - or, that a bug somewhere else in the code is going to do something to a similar effect.

Introducing an enum isn't going to change that. You'll still have to parse the raw `string` into an enum value. If the next thing you do is then to `switch` on the enum to produce a polymorphic object, you might as well dispense with the intermediary step, and hence, with the enum.

This discussion is reminiscent of Alexis King's great blog post [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate), which makes a similar point: turn something less-structured into something with a better structure.

Answer (score 4):

The direction of the dependency is fine. There is another problem, though. When a new enumerator is added due to a change in the requirements, both sides of the boundary have to change. This violates the open-closed principle. We want to be able to make changes that do not affect the higher level side of the boundary.

If you use a string, instead, then adding the new condition below the line does not force any change above the line.

You may rightly ask how the high level side learns about the strings. It turns out that the high level side can ask the low level side for all the relevant strings.

Thus, by using strings, instead of enums, you can protect the high level code from changes to the lower level requirements.

Comment: *"When a new enumerator is added due to a change in the requirements, both sides of the boundary have to change*" Yes, on the other hand, with the proposed design, while you can add new values to switch on, if you need to add a new capability (a new method), both sides have to change. This is known as the [Expression Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). You probably already know that, but I'll leave it here for other interested readers.